# Where Do We Place Elements in a Larger Resized Hashtable?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm new to learning about data structures and algorithms. My question is about hash tables. Let's say we have elements (x for each key) in a hashtable (size = 10), placed using linear probing (hash function is x % 10), and we decide to increase the size of the hashtable to 15.

How do we decide where the elements go in the new larger hashtable? Do we simply iterate over the older hashtable, calculate a new hash for each element with a different hash function (say x % 15), and place the element in the new hashtable using linear probing?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding of the most common resize operation. The hashtable is increased in size by a constant factor (typically doubling) and all the elements are rehashed. This happens when the load factor exceeds some constant value.

Comment: @jarmod thank you for your response. That answered my question. I didn't know if there was anything more complex that had to be done to place the elements in the new hash table.

Comment: You should use prime numbers for the size when practical as that tends to produce a better distribution of keys for typical keys. Obviously, YMMV.